# The binding property is coming null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new at this and trying to figure out what happen and think this is the best place to ask. Well when I select the project and press the add button the property [Bind""]Model came null but why?

This is my View:

```
@model PortfolioDetailsVM
<form asp-controller="Portfolio" asp-action="AddProject" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <select asp-for="PortfolioProjects.ProjectId" class="custom-select form-control">
                <option disabled selected value="@null">Choose...</option>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Projects)
                {
                    <option value="@item.ProjectID">@item.Title</option>
                }
            </select>
```

The var PortfolioVM came null with any data.
And this is my Controller and my View Model:

```
namespace PEG.Models
{
    public class PortfolioDetailsVM
    {
        public PortfolioDetailsVM()
        {
            Portfolios = new Portfolio();
            PortfolioProjects = new PortfolioProject();
        }
        public Portfolio Portfolio;
        public PortfolioProject PortfolioProjects;
        public IEnumerable<Project> Projects;
    }
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddProject([Bind("PortfolioProject")]PortfolioDetailsVM PortfolioVM) //<----Null
{
    var addproject = PortfolioVM.PortfolioProjects;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            context.Update(addproject);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Portfolio" + PortfolioVM.PortfolioProjects.PortfolioId);
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
            "Try again, and if the problem persists, " +
            "see your system administrator.");
        }

    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Portfolio");
}
```

This the other model and Details Method:

```
 // GET: Portfolio/Details/5
    public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int id)
    {
        PortfolioDetailsVM PortfolioVM = new PortfolioDetailsVM
        {
            Projects = await context.Project.Include(x => x.Task).ToListAsync(),
            Portfolios = await context.Portfolio.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.PortfolioID == id)
        };

        return View(PortfolioVM);
    }
namespace PEG.Models
{
    public partial class PortfolioProject
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

        //RelationsId
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        public int PortfolioId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public string ProjectId { get; set; }

        //Relations
        [ForeignKey("PortfolioId")]
        public virtual Portfolio Portfolio { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
        public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your code that calls this method?

Comment: @JamesS  I post the view that call the controller.

Comment: Post `Details` method  of Controller `Portfolio`.

Comment: @Sumitraj I post the Porfolio Method

Comment: @JonathanPadilla you have posted `Portfolio` class structure not the method. There should be a method with name `Details` in `Portfolio` controller. Post the method.

Comment: @Sumitraj Sorry now I put the detais controller method.

Comment: Have u debugged to check weather `PortfolioVM` contains data before returnig from `Details` method?

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo of the actual problem, but you have `asp-for="PortfolioProjects.ProjectId"`, with `PortfolioProjects`, plural. It should be singular based on your model.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yeah I changed that, but still having the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Bind to properties

First off, you have defined fields in your ViewModels. They can be read in your View, but for Model Binding to work you need to declare them as **Properties**, with a get and set accessor:

```
public class PortfolioDetailsVM
{
    //...

    public Portfolio Portfolio { get; set; }
    public PortfolioProject PortfolioProject { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

This should make your binding code work.

### Better binding models

Second, you are using Model Binding in a slightly incorrect way. Try not to bind directly to your data models (e.g. the type of PortfolioProject). The model you're binding to shouldn't contain any reference to data model types.

Instead, I usually only declare what I really need in the model I'm binding to, so that I won't ever have to use that ol' `Bind` attribute in the first place. A simple example for your case:

```
public class DetailsAddProjectVM
{
    public string SelectedProjectId { get; set; }
}
```

With a corresponding form:

```
@model PortfolioDetailsVM
<select asp-for="SelectedProjectId" class="custom-select form-control">
   ...
</select>
```

which posts to

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddProject(DetailsAddProjectVM bindingModel)
{
   //look ma, no [Bind]!
   var projectid = bindingModel.SelectedProjectId;
}
```

Of course, for the corresponding form to render, you'd also have to declare a `SelectedProjectId` property in your original `PortfolioDetailsVM`.

As you can see, you don't **have** to bind to your original View Model at all.

Comment: Yes! finally I grab the data Thanks! but now when I gonna save I receive: The property 'PortfolioID' on entity type 'PortfolioProject' has a temporary value.